# Python - Reading a File in Single/Multi-line Pieces

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python, I have found answers to most of my issues here but this one has me stumped.

I am processing log files using Python, generally every line starts with a date/time stamp such as:

```
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST]
```

In 99% of cases I can read line by line, look for items of interest and process them accordingly however occasionally an entry in the log file will include a message that has carriage return / new line characters in it, as such it will span multiple lines.

Is there a way I can easily read the file "between timestamps" such that when this situation occurs the multiple lines would be consolidated in to one read instead? For example:

```
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] Another log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry that somehow
got some new line
characters mixed in
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] The last log entry
```

Would be read as four lines rather than six as it is now.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Chris,

Update....

myTestFile.log contains the exact text above, here is my script:

```
import sys, getopt, os, re
sourceFolder = 'C:/MaxLogs'
logFileName = sourceFolder + "/myTestFile.log"
lines = []

def timestamp_split(file):
    pattern = re.compile("\[(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\/)(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\/)([0-9]{2})(\ )")
    current = []
    for line in file:
        if not re.match(pattern,line):
            if current:
                yield "".join(current)
            current == [line]
        else:
            current.append(line)
    yield "".join(current)

print "--- START ----"
with open(logFileName) as file:
    for entry in timestamp_split(file):
        print entry
        print "- Record Separator -"
print "--- DONE ----"
```

When I run it I get this:

```
--- START ----
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] Another log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry that somehow

- Record Separator -
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] Another log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry that somehow

- Record Separator -
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] Another log entry
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry that somehow
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] The last log entry
- Record Separator -
--- DONE ----
```

I seem to be iterating through the lines too many times, what I was expecting (hoping) for was this:

```
--- START ----
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry
- Record Separator -
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] Another log entry
- Record Separator -
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] A log entry that somehow got some new line characters mixed in
- Record Separator -
[1/4/13 18:37:37:848 PST] The last log entry
- Record Separator -
--- DONE ----
```

As discussed in the comments I accidentally left the *not* in the comparison with the regex pattern from when I was testing, if I remove it then I get all of the partial lines which confuses me even more!

```
--- START ----
got some new line
characters mixed in

- Record Separator -
got some new line
characters mixed in

- Record Separator -
--- DONE ----
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to implement a simple generator to do this:

```
def timestamp_split(file):
    current = []
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("["):
            if current:
                yield "".join(current)
            current == [line]
        else:
            current.append(line)
    yield "".join(current)
```

Naturally, this assumes `"["` at the start of a line is enough to signify a timestamp - you might want to do a more significant check.

Then just do something like:

```
with open("somefile.txt") as file:
    for entry in timestamp_split(file):
        ...
```

(Here using [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4&) - a good practice for opening files.)

Comment: Looks great, thank you, I have a regexp for matching to the time stamp so I think I can modify your code above to do a match to that rather than relying on the [ - I think that should make it robust enough, I don't think a similar timestamp will appear elsewhere in my data.

Comment: Feeling close... I still seem to get odd results, is there something I am missing?

Comment: @Chris You want to check if the pattern *does* match the start of the line. The `if` block should execute if it **is** a timestamped line.

Comment: I tested the pattern, it matches the time stamp as I would expect it to but still gives the output shown above. Unless I am printing the wrong thing I never seem to get the *extra* lines, it seems to concatenate the time stamp lines instead. Maybe this is because I "print entry" and it is actually a list not a string? Should I be printing each item in entry if entry is indeed a list? I was assuming that .join is a string concatenation...?

Comment: Just realized I had left the *not* in there when I was testing... if I remove it then I get this.... which is equally perplexing (to me!).

--- START ----
got some new line
characters mixed in

    - Record Separator -
    got some new line
    characters mixed in
    
    - Record Separator -
    --- DONE ----

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

lines = []
pattern = re.compile('\[\d+/\d+/\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s\w+\]')
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match(pattern, line):
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            lines[-1] += line
```

This matches the timestamps with a regular expression. Can adjust it as needed. It also assumes that the first line contains a timestamp.

Comment: This also builds the entire list up-front, which could cause problems if these files are extremely large.

Comment: If you _don't_ mind reading the whole file up front, you can greatly simplify the above by using `re.split()` on the whole file instead of examining each line.

Comment: Unlike a generator, this allows you to do other things with the resulting list instead of just iterating over them once (unless you convert the generator to a list again, in which case you didn't need it in the first place), and it should be significantly faster than `re.split()`, although I didn't test that part. As usual, it depends on what you're after.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac It's good practice to provide a generator - this allows the user to work lazily in most situations, and if they *need* a list, they can make one. See the entire standard library getting fixed to function like this in 3.x

Comment: I noticed, to my great annoyance :\ I do see the point in it, but I'd prefer if they offered both versions, to save some unnecessary overhead when and where necessary. Generators trade off space-complexity for time-complexity, which I find extremely odd, because time is almost always more worrisome than space. The situations where that isn't the case are the ones you'll care enough to specify a generator expression for (which this one may actually fall under, because log files can be huge). It's one of a number of odd design choices for Py3k imo.